# Enumeration error after renew

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I wanted to reduce the space between the items in all the enumerations in a document, so I renewed the environment using

```
\let\oldenum\enumerate
\let\oldendenum\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\oldenum\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}}{\oldendenum}
```

But then when I tried to change the label of an enumeration to use roman number I got an error saying `Missing number, treated as zero`. Here is a simple code reproducing the error. Anybody has an idea what is the problem here??

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}


\let\oldenum\enumerate
\let\oldendenum\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\oldenum\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}}{\oldendenum}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)] % THIS THROWS A COMPILATION ERROR
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you define `\smallskipamount`?

Comment: @TeXnician: `\smallskipamount` is a LaTeX built in, as far as I know

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I did not know. But then why should someone use `enumitem` and set parskip manually?

Comment: there is no reason to redefine enumerate, all the spacing in the environment may be set by parameters either directly or using `enumitem` setup as you have loaded that package.

Comment: @Rodrigo I tried it. But why don't you use `enumitem`'s `parsep` property? It does your task.

Comment: your enviroment is equivalent to `\begin{oldenum}\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}[label=\roman*)] ` so clearly the old environment will not see the optional argument.

Comment: @TeXnician method works for me. I didn't know about it (I'm a still bit new to latex). Thank for your help people.

Comment: @TeXnician: Someone who does not read manuals ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`'s options to define distances between paragraphs. This code should work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=\smallskipamount}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)]
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing between items depends on `itemsep`, not `parsep`.

Comment: @Bernard That is right, but the original question also only renewed `\parskip`, so I described `parsep`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution with `enumitem` and `itemsep` is cleaner because it is supported by the package already.

I give a way using the redefinition of the environment, just for completeness.

Since `enumerate` has an optional argument, `\let` is not sufficient, but using `\LetLtxMacro` from the package `\letltxmacro` cares for this catching.

The optional argument must be catched for the `\renewenvironment` as well, otherwise the `[....]` will be misunderstood.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\LetLtxMacro\oldenum\enumerate
\LetLtxMacro\oldendenum\endenumerate


\begin{document}

{%
\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)] 
\item one 
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
}


{%
\hrule
\parskip=\smallskipamount
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)] % THIS IS THROWN A COMPILATION ERROR
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
}


\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][]{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
  \oldenum[#1]}{\oldendenum}

\hrule
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*)] % THIS IS THROWN A COMPILATION ERROR
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that explains a lot, thanks for your answer! I'm still learning some of the basics, so I appreciate this.